# Testing ErrorInterceptor in Angular 8

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to write unit-testing for ErrorInterceptor:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HttpErrorInterceptorService } from './http-error-interceptor.service';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

const testUrl = '/api/v1/auth/signin';

describe('HttpErrorInterceptorService', () => {
  let service: HttpErrorInterceptorService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let authService: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: HttpErrorInterceptorService,
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(HttpErrorInterceptorService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should catch error when calling api', async() => {
    const fakeURL = '/api/v1/auth/signin';
    const fakeDataToBeSend = {
      password: 'Daniel',
      email: 'daniel.danielecki@foo.com'
    };

    spyOn(window, 'alert');

    await authService.login(fakeDataToBeSend).subscribe();

    httpMock
      .expectOne(fakeURL)
      .error(new ErrorEvent('Network error.'));

    expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Network error.');

  });  

});
```

In the `http-error-interceptor.service.ts` I have :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,  HttpInterceptor,  HttpHandler,  HttpRequest,  HttpResponse,  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HttpErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('--------------')
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log('kkkkkkkkkkk')

        let errorMessage = '';
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
        } else {
          errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
        }
        window.alert(errorMessage);
        return throwError(errorMessage);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

In the auth.service I have

```
  login(user: ILoginUser): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('/api/v1/auth/signin', user);
  }
```

I tried hard but `should catch error when calling api` is not working.

Please help

Comment: Can you recreate in https://stackblitz.com/ or similar?

Comment: ok, but i dont know how to add UT in slackblitz. but i will try